# await Task.WhenAll does not wait for all tasks to complete

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I've been experimenting lately with async-await and I still cannot get some things to work.

Why does this code not always result with '100' being written to console?

Should not

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

wait for all 100 tasks to complete?

```
static List<int> list = new List<int>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    NewMethod();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private async static void NewMethod()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(Func(i));
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Lol");

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    Console.WriteLine(list.Count());
}

static async Task Func(int i)
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    list.Add(i);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this some kind of async-await downside?

Same goes with

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

which I wasn't sure at first if it's equal in this case.

There are a few similar questions but my example is really simple and I can't find explanation in the existing answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason you experience the inconsistency in the number of elements is because `List<T>` isn't *thread-safe*.

After you `await Task.Delay(100)`, the continuation, which adds elements to the list happens on an arbitrary thread pool, **concurrently**, because multiple tasks are executing. If you switch you implementation to use `ConcurrentBag<int>`, this wont happen.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a lock(list) before adding the int to the list. You potentially adding from multiple threads to a non thread safe list.

Comment: Lock is not the most performant way. Using either System.Collections.Concurrent.* or a ReaderWriterLock is far more efficient...

Comment: Absolutely - Using lock has been chosen only because it makes it easy to reason about the solution and original problem. Performance was never a consideration.

Answer (score 2):

- Do not use list with multi-threaded code - access in unsafe - use one of the collections in System.Collections.Concurrent.
- Never use 'async void' - it is a horrible thing to support async click handlers in .Net UI applications (http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/)

The following code will work for your purposes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly BlockingCollection<int> List = new BlockingCollection<int>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var application = NewMethod();
            application.Wait();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private async static Task NewMethod()
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                tasks.Add(Func(i));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Lol");

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

            Console.WriteLine(List.Sum());
        }

        static async Task Func(int i)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            List.Add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The async void was an effect of quick 'extract method' refactoring but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Only writing to List in multi-threaded code is a problem, reading should be just fine.

Comment: Agreed @Ben - however it's only a matter of time before someone comes along and 'refactors' something. I think it's safer, especially in larger teams, to use concurrent collections when there is any chance of multi-threaded access, as it prevents hard-to-find bugs later down the road.

Comment: @BenVoigt If you *never* write to it, yes. But writing on one thread and reading on multiple is still unsafe. And of course, it's not a contractual behaviour, so it could change in the future